# Iterate over a nested dictionary format and save the output result

Tags: python-3.x, loops, dictionary, for-loop, nested

I was looking but didn´t found something regarding iterate over one nested dictionary and save the output.

This is the dictionary:

```
 dictionary={
    "A": "EXAMPLE",
    "comment": "This is an example",
    "author": "JKROWLING",
    "book1": [
        {
            "book_name": 'place book name',
            "amount_pages":'place book_pages' 
        }
    ]
}
```

Now I have a df with the following information:

```
data = {'book_name': ['philosopher', 'chamber', 'azkaban', 'goblet', 'phoenix','prince','hallow'],
        'amount_page': [220, 280, 330, 450, 1000,650,600]
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

print(df)
```

I don´t know how to iterate a dataframe or a list in a dictionary and save the results. I mean, the expected ouput is to get all the book_name and amount of pages in different dictionaries. The expected output would be

```
{
    "A": "EXAMPLE",
    "comment": "This is an example",
    "author": "JKROWLING",
    "book1": [
        {
            "book_name": 'philosopher',
            "amount_pages":220 
        }
    ]
}

 dictionary={
    "A": "EXAMPLE",
    "comment": "This is an example",
    "author": "JKROWLING",
    "book1": [
        {
            "book_name": 'Chamber',
            "amount_pages":280
        }
    ]
}

 dictionary={
    "A": "EXAMPLE",
    "comment": "This is an example",
    "author": "JKROWLING",
    "book1": [
        {
            "book_name": 'Azkaban',
            "amount_pages":330
        }
    ]
}
```

Until the end of the dataframe.... I need all the values in different dictionaries

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `zip()` + for-loop to get names/pages from the dataframe and store the dictionaries in the list:

```py
out = []
for n, p in zip(df["book_name"], df["amount_page"]):
    dictionary = {
        "A": "EXAMPLE",
        "comment": "This is an example",
        "author": "JKROWLING",
        "book1": [{"book_name": n, "amount_pages": p}],
    }
    out.append(dictionary)

print(out)
```

Prints:

```
[
    {
        "A": "EXAMPLE",
        "comment": "This is an example",
        "author": "JKROWLING",
        "book1": [{"book_name": "philosopher", "amount_pages": 220}],
    },
    {
        "A": "EXAMPLE",
        "comment": "This is an example",
        "author": "JKROWLING",
        "book1": [{"book_name": "chamber", "amount_pages": 280}],
    },
    {
        "A": "EXAMPLE",
        "comment": "This is an example",
        "author": "JKROWLING",
        "book1": [{"book_name": "azkaban", "amount_pages": 330}],
    },

...
```